# Matplotlib: set_rmin not working for logarithmic polar projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm, polar-coordinates

I am trying to plot a grid data in polar projection. However, I would need to set the minimal value on the Y (r) axis, but the set_rmin() seems not to be working - disregarding of the value putt in, the plot does not change.

Also, the minor issue, does anyone know how to plot the grid OVER the actual colorplot? So far I have fixed it by drawing circles around manually, but this seems to be rather inelegant.

Cheers

Attached is the plotting part of the script:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[x,y], projection="polar")
ax1.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax1.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax1.set_rmin(0.5)
ax1.set_rscale('log')
im=ax1.pcolormesh(theta,r,dataMasked.T, vmin = 0.5, vmax =  vmax_,cmap='spectral')
im.cmap.set_bad('w',1.)
ax1.set_yticks(range(0, 90, 15))
ax1.yaxis.grid(True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `ax1.set_rmin(0.5)` *after* you set `ax1.set_rscale('log')`. You may also need to set `ax1.set_rmax()` to an appropriate value.

**EDIT:**

Looks like you need to set `rscale = log`, then `rmax`, then `rmin`, otherwise it won't work:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: ax1 = plt.subplot(111, projection="polar")

In [3]: ax1.get_rmin(), ax1.get_rmax()
Out[3]: (0.0, 1.0) # Looks ok

In [4]: ax1.set_rmin(0.5)

In [5]: ax1.get_rmin(), ax1.get_rmax()
Out[5]: (0.5, 1.0) # Looks ok

In [6]: ax1.set_rscale('log')

In [7]: ax1.get_rmin(), ax1.get_rmax()
        # Setting rscale=log changes both rmin and rmax
Out[7]: (9.9999999999999995e-08, 1.0000000000000001e-05) 

In [8]: ax1.set_rmin(0.5)

In [9]: ax1.get_rmin(), ax1.get_rmax()
        # OK, so that didn't work, because we were trying to  
        # set rmin to a value greater than rmax
Out[9]: (1.0000000000000001e-05, 0.5)

         # Set both rmax and rmin (rmax first)
In [10]: ax1.set_rmax(1); ax1.set_rmin(0.5)

In [11]: ax1.get_rmin(), ax1.get_rmax()
Out[11]: (0.5, 1.0) # Success!
```

Comment: seems like order is very important. See my upcoming edit.

Comment: Great idea, approach.. Its finally working now. Thank you. Its weird is messes up both y-limits, but then the polar projection is not so easy to implement I guess

Comment: Yes, I don't know why it should change both limits to such small numbers with logscale. Well, at least it works now. Please consider accepting the answer so others know your problem is resolved :)